# Why does console.log(10+5+rajdeep) gives 15rajdeep as the output and console.log(rajdeep+10+5) gives rajdeep105 as the output?

Tags: javascript

console.log(10+5+rajdeep);
console.log(rajdeep+10+5);
First statement gives 15rajdeep.
Second statement gives rajdeep105.

Comment: Radeep is most likely a string..

Comment: Because the additions are resolved left to right; in the first case, you're adding numbers *before* coercing anything to a string.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to expand on [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)'s comment.

For the sake of being precise I'm going to assume that `rajdeep` is a variable that stores the string `'rajdeep'`. Javascript evaluates addition operations right to left. That is to say that `10+5+rajdeep` is actually evaluated as `((10+5)+rajdeep)`. From the [Mozilla docs on arithmetic operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) we can see that `10+5` will evaluate to `15` first which is then concatenated with the `rajdeep` string to produce `15rajdeep`. The second example `rajdeep+10+5` is evaluated as `((rajdeep+10)+5)`. `rajdeep+10` produces a string `rajdeep10` which is then added to 5 to produce another string `rajdeep105`.